# como hacer que mi matriz no multiplique por 10

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa que cree una matriz de 10*10, en la primer columna debera contar desde 1 hasta 10 , pero incrementando las filas a partir el primer numero de la columna. Estuve investigando un poco y encontré que con `foreach()` puedo hacer lo que necesito pero al checar la salida esta multiplicando los valores por 10.

[image: Como en el siguiente ejemplo]

Este es mi codigo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace mtriz
{
 class PruebaMatriz
{

    private int[,] mat;
    private int x = 10;
    private int acc = 0;
    public void Cargar()
    {
        mat = new int[x, x];
        for(int f = 0; f < x; f++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < x; c++)
            {

                foreach(int aac in mat)
                {
                    acc = acc + 1;
                mat[f, c] = f + acc;

                }
               
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void Imprimir()
    {
        for(int f = 0; f < x; f++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < x; c++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}",+mat[f, c] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PruebaMatriz pm = new PruebaMatriz();
        pm.Cargar();
        pm.Imprimir();
    }
 }
}
```

y esta es mi salida:

[image: Salida multiplicando los valores *10]

No entiendo porque multiplica por 10 o que es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: el foreach sobra totalmetne.. por eso te esta multiplicando por 10